# How to install Selenium package in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, spyder

I've just installed Spyder IDE (only Spyder, not whole Anaconda) at work and would like to automate my work with FireFox.

My question is, how do I install the Selenium package?

Comment: do you already have Python installed? Spyder is just an IDE, not the language itself. After installing Python, I would recommend you to build a virtual environment and install Selenium on it (along other packages you may need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is instruction for Windows:

1. Install Python: 
   https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Install Spyder: 
   https://www.spyder-ide.org/
3. Run PowerShell or CMD:
4. Insert following commands:

   pip install selenium  
   pip install webdriver_manager
5. Use command "pip freeze", you should see among others, following libraries installed: 
   selenium==3.141.0 
   urllib3==1.26.2 
   webdriver-manager==3.2.2
6. Open Spyder -> Tools -> PYTHONPATH manager -> Add path 
   c:\users\Hronic\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages

**Note:**  
If you don't know the path, in CMD/PowerShell, type "PIP install selenium" 
You will get the answer: 
"Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\Hronic\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.26.2)"

7. Download webdriver - in my case mozilla: 
   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
8. In Spyder, you can type following code:

   from selenium import webdriver 
   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Hronic\Downloads\geckodriver.exe') 
   driver.get("http://www.python.org")

**Note:**

- path to just downloaded driver
- this short code should open firefox and webpage "http://www.python.org"

9. It should work or rather "works for me" :)

Comment: Please don't use our PYTHOnPATH manager for this. It's the incorrect way of doing it. Instead follow the instructions I posted below.

Comment: And what's wrong with path manager?
As I understand, IDE can't find installed libraries so i help it a little bit.

Comment: Because by doing that you're mixing two Python installations, which will give odd errors and segfaults for packages like Pandas and Numpy.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) First, you need to download [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), create an [environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) and install Selenium on it with `conda install selenium`. Then you need to connect Spyder to your environment so you can run code that depends on Selenium on it.

The entire process is better described in the second part of [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) about managing environments.