# How to install and import selenium into spyder

Tags: python, selenium, data-science, spyder

I am working on a project which uses Selenium however, Spyder simply refuses to import or even install it. I have read a few answers to similar problems and have tried:

```
pip install selenium

pip3 install selenium

sudo pip install selenium

sudo pip3 install selenium
```

as is usually suggested.

Each time the console says the syntax is invalid. Whenever I try to import selenium it says Module not found. Why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder mantainer suggest to install it via anaconda/miniconda [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65163127/13147413).

Try like this:

```
conda install selenium
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I tried this already and with sudo in front as well if that makes any difference. I am using the latest version of Spyder and Anaconda.

Comment: Have you activated the environment?

Did you tried restarting the terminal/shell you are using?

Comment: I have (press F6). Other packages work, just not Selenium.

Comment: Try using the system terminal instead of the the spyder one.

Beside that you i cannot help you further if you do not provide more complete infos.